# OS X App Codesign issue

Tags: macos, codesign

I have an OS X app which uses a custom built flow outside of XCode. Therefore, I have to use the codesign tool in command line mode to sign everything within the app. The command line I used is:

> codesign -f -s "Developer ID Application: MyCompany Inc" -i com.mycompany.myapp -v $Path_To_App

I first signed every binary, framework and plugins within the app by passing the path of each one of them as $Path_To_App. Then I signed the whole app by passing the path of the app folder MyApp.app.

After that, I used the following command to build a dmg file:

> hdiutil create -format UDBZ -srcfolder path_to_app_folder myapp.dmg

If I install this dmg file locally, everything is fine. I believe OS X doesn't even check the certificates in this case. But after I upload the dmg file to the web server, download it with a browser and extract the app into the Applications folder, the OS rejects the app as damaged. The message is:

"MyApp" is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the trash.

If I check the signature like this, it is fine:

> codesign --verify --verbose /Applications/MyApp.app

/Applications/MyApp.app: valid on disk
/Applications/MyApp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

However, if I check it with spctl, it does complain:

> spctl -a -v /Applications/MyApp.app
>   /Applications/MyApp.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid

I am not sure where I do wrong here. Here is the url of the signed dmg file on the web: http://www.slimjet.com/test/slimjet1.dmg .

### Thanks a lot for helping!

Here is an update. The damage warning only shows up when I extract the app into the /Applications folder and run it from there. If I drop it into any other folder and run, or directly run it from mounted dmg archive, it is able to run just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the gatekeeper keeps cached information about previous failures. Even if you fix the problem by applying all the correct signatures later on, spctl command still reports the same error without actually checking it again. The codesign command doesn't use cache but spctl does. I had to reset the system policy database by the following command:

> sudo cp /var/db/.SystemPolicy-default /var/db/SystemPolicy

After that, I restart the OS. Then my app runs just fine. Although spctl has a "--ignore-cache" switch, it doesn't have any effect in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to also codesign:

```
FlashPeak Slimjet.app/Contents/Versions/13.0.6.0/FlashPeak Slimjet Helper.app
FlashPeak Slimjet.app/Contents/Versions/13.0.6.0/FlashPeak Slimjet Framework.framework/Resources/app_mode_loader.app
```

Since they not codesigned this is probably the issue; there could be others, but check these first.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've signed these two apps and double checked the entire app folder. But I still run into the same error when I download the new dmg file (still at the url).